# Тепловая карта транспортной доступности и инфраструктуры для Яндекс Карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

У серивса Яндекс.Недвижимость в режиме карты, есть опция включить слои "Транспортная доступность" и "Инфраструктура". Такое же я хочу реализовать для себя. Уже понял что это делается через Тепловые карты.
Но встает вопрос: где взять все эти многочисленные параметры, чтобы воссоздать подобное? То есть нет ли такой возможности их автоматически получить от яндекса, хотя бы для Москвы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы считаете, что Яндексу есть резон делиться тщательно собираемыми и обрабатываемыми датасетами, которые делают их сервисы уникальными с своём сегменте? Если они нигде публично такую возможность не опубликовали, значит информация закрытая. Ищите подобную в публичных источниках.